# Interpolate ruby variable for data attribute?

Tags: ruby, variables, attributes, haml

In a .html.haml file, I have a button:

```
%button{:data=>{'foo'=> @bar}, type:'button', 'id'=>'confirmBtn'} Confirm
```

However, the data attribute is not picking up anything. What is the proper way to interpolate ruby variables in this case?

Comment: Is `@bar` set to anything?

Comment: Yes. It is a boolean variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
%button{ data: { foo: @bar.to_s }, type: 'button', id: 'confirmBtn' } Confirm
```

I've changed the syntax in the above line a bit, but what you should do is change `@bar` to `@bar.to_s` (as tadman suggested). It looks cleaner than `"#{@bar}"` what I suggested earlier.

Comment: `@bar.to_s` is also an option here if casting from a boolean is required.

Comment: It's also nice to add that why you changed his syntax.